# Enable Caching for cshtml files without an associated controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack, single-page-application

I am working on a single page application (SPA) using ServiceStack as the API provider, there are two cshtml pages avaiable, index.cshtml and admin.cshtml. The only reason for these files being cshtml as opposed to simple html is the leveraging of Asp.Net System.Web.Optimization.

I am trying to figure out how to enable Output Caching considering I don't have controllers available. I know if I had controllers I would use the OutputCacheAttribute.

I also understand that the app needs to be refactored, but for sake of time, I need to make it work in the current structure. Any help would be mostly appreciated.

P.S. I am also trying to avoid overwriting the output headers as I don't want to have to manage the ETag myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Response.OutputCache() extension method:

```
@{
    Response.OutputCache(30);
 }
```

It has lots of parameters which allow you to specify the same things as you would in the OutputCache attribute.

Here is the documentation:

```
public static void 
OutputCache
(this System.Web.HttpResponseBase response,
int numberOfSeconds, [bool sliding = false], 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> varyByParams = null], 
[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> varyByHeaders = null], 
[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> varyByContentEncodings = null], 
[System.Web.HttpCacheability cacheability = System.Web.HttpCacheability.Public])
```

Comment: That's easy enough. Visual Studio seems to have a problem with the syntax... but it's working. Thank you